# Alternative for "It is also..."

Tags: synonyms

I tend to use *"it is also"* often in scientific text. I have been asked to correct following parts:

> *It is also* looked into the surplus

... and...

> *It is also* that the business

... and...

> *It is also* considered

... and ... ...

There is many more than these. The habit comes from my native language, where there is a structure which allows linking sentences similarly to "it is also", but a much more elegant. Thus I need an alternative word or structure to remove few of the *"it is also"*.

Comment: I have no idea what "it is also" is intended to mean here.

Comment: "It is also" is supposed to link two sentences. Like: "Consumers use a product for value. It is also that the business is making profit" And I tend to use that far too often.

Comment: You mean it means “and”?

Comment: @user3644640 This isn't idiomatic in English, so far as I'm aware; given that, you might revert to the simple strategy of using conjunctions: "Consumers use a product for value, and the business makes a profit". No need to split it into two sentences in the first place, IMO.

Comment: @DanBron The conjuction straregy would not work that often, for example in these cases: http://www.linguee.com/english-japanese/search?query=it+is+also *"It is also"* allows some distance between the sentences. You can explain X and the deeper nature of it before it is also told that Y has a part in it too.

Comment: Additionally, furthermore.

Comment: Those words provided by Davo and conjunction strategy solve some cases, but not all. Many cases where using "we" or "I" forcefully made to passive still require that *"it is also"*, but those two answers allow me to reduce amount significantly.

Comment: The first one is definitely bogus and simply needs to be reworded with different idioms.  Can't tell about the other two.  (You might want to try using `In addition,`.)

Comment: The above comments suggest that the sample sentences in your question don't express your intent sufficiently well. In particular, the phrase or sentence that precedes "it is also" is missing in each case, and it's unclear how distant you intend them to be from the parts that follow "it is also". It would help for you to [edit] your question to add a sentence or a pair of sentences or a paragraph in which the proposed construct would be used.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are having so much of a problem with a particular phrase, make a concerted effort to **never use that phrase.** Two of your three examples have improper syntax: they don't make sense.

Even in scientific journals, using pronouns other than "it" are okay.

*Our team discovered ...*

*Next, we prepared the sample for infusion . ...*

As the comments advised, *furthermore, additionally,* or a thesaurus word of choice will work for some of your uses.

Also, vary your sentence structure, even in a scientific paper. Adverbial or prepositional phrases work.

*After the flood, our team collected samples from ...*

*In the mass spectrometer, ...*

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to say, **alternatively** in the beginning, but *it is* would still be present after.
Another option - **in addition (to)**
If something causes something - **consequently**
**More than that** - also a good choice in some instances.